# Metro UI Css - Navigation bar positioning with visible side menu

Tags: html, css

I am testing the Metro UI CSS framework to make an application mockup and I am having a problem with the positioning of the navigation bar.

- **Documentation:** https://metroui.org.ua/intro.html
- **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/prkc0mfL/ `line 23 onwards`

In the example attached, when the menu button is pressed on small screens, the application layer moves to the right (navigation bar and content) and shows the layer where the menu will be located on the left. The problem is that for long pages, the navigation bar goes up with the page when scrolling.

I need the side scrolling of the application layer to be preserved, as it currently does, but the navigation bar to be fixed when scrolling.

I have gone through the documentation for the framework and I cannot find the combination of classes I need to do this. Can somebody help me? I have tried almost every combination of positions and I can't do it.

I hope you can tell me where my mistake is.

A greeting.

Comment: Did you try `pos-fixed` instead of `pos-absolute`? https://jsfiddle.net/pexqczkr/

Comment: Yes, i tried it, but when opening the menu it is positioned above the button instead of moving it to the right as it currently does https://jsfiddle.net/s8kboz0v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simpler than I thought, it was enough to add `style="overflow-y: auto"` and with that it was solved.

https://jsfiddle.net/fs6qkt9b/ `line 33`